# Can't connect to my nexus repository by using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, nexus

I've got following build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
buildscript {

repositories {
    maven {
      url "<myURL>/nexus/content/groups/public"
   }
}
    dependencies {

    }
}


jar {
   baseName = 'myAppName'
   version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {

maven {
      url "<myURL>/nexus/content/groups/public/"
      credentials {
        username "nexusUser"
        password "nexusPassword"
    }
}
maven {
      url "<myURL>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
      credentials {
        username "nexusUser"
        password "nexusPassword"
    }
}
}
dependencies {

compile group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '7.0'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.5'
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
}

uploadArchives {

repositories {
   mavenDeployer {
         repository(url: "<myURL>/content/repositories/releases") {
            authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
          }
         snapshotRepository(url: "<myURL>/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots") {
         authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
    }

         pom.version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
         pom.artifactId = "app-name-commons"
         pom.groupId = "de.commons"
   }
}
}
```

My Problem is that I can't neither upload artifacts to my nexus repo nore I get the dependencies like javaee-api etc. The credential are defined in a gradle.properties file. Has anybody a hint why this doesn't work?

**Update**

If I make the repositories readable for anonymous users i get the dependencies. So it seems the problem is the login.

Comment: You have defined your repo twice. With credentials and once without credentials. Is it this one?

Comment: you're right. I forgot that. I just edited an existing script without using nexus. I just added the credential to both and getting dependencies work now. But the upload still doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you declare the repositories three times with partly duplicate content? Just make your script easier and it should work.